Add dependencies to .NET MAUI Android
I have an MAUI application that should be run on Windows and Android devices. I need to add some DLLs to the application so I can load those DLLs by reflection in runtime. I copied DLLs to the /Resources/Raw folder and then built the project for Android, but I couldn't find those DDLs with reflection. Seems those DLLs are not being included in the package.
Note: Everything works fine in Windows.
.NET: 8
Target Framework: "net8.0-android;net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0"

Add them as a reference to your project, why are you adding them to your Resources?

Open the generated APK file in a ZIP tool and search for your dll files, then you will see where they end up when you place them in Resources/Raw

You can check this thread to use the dll on the windows platform. For the Android platform, you can't use a dll on the Android.
